# How to create list of 15-digit numbers with condition?

Tags: python, list, random, numbers

I want to create list of random 20 15-digit numbers and each of this 15-digit numbers must follow 1 rule.

The rule is that I want this 15-digit number to be made out of 5 3-digit numbers in which **first digit + second digit = third digit** or if sum of first two digits is greater than 10 then **third digit must be, equal to *second digit* of sum of first two digits.** for example if first digit is 5 and second is 8, third digit must be 3 since 5 + 8 = 13.

I've written code that fills list with 15-digit numbers with the same rule, but it only works for first three digits.

```
import random as rd
def numchoose(start, end):
arr=[]
num=0
while num<20:
   a=(rd.randint(start, end))
   if int(str(a)[0]) + int(str(a)[1]) == int(str(a)[2]):
       arr.append(a)
       num+=1
   elif int(str(a)[0]) + int(str(a)[1]) > 10 and int(str(a)[2]) == int(str(int(str(a)[0]) +
int(str(a)[1]))[1])  :
      arr.append(a)
      num+=1
   else: continue


print(numchoose(100000000000000, 999999999999999))
```

How do I write this code so that entire 15-digit number is made out of 3-digit numbers that follow the stated rule and first three digits are not the only ones that follow rule?

Comment: Work more with strings. Create a function to return 3-digit number according to rules converted to string. Call these function 5 times, concatenate strings and finally convert it to int.

Comment: That doesn't seem very random to me.  You might be able to make a list of all the 3-digit combinations that meet the rule and use `random.choice` to pick from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work, but i replaced the big number with how long you want the number to be.

```
import random as rd

def numchoose(len):
    number = ""
    for i in range(int(len/3)):
        a = rd.randint(0, 9)

        while i == 0 and a == 0:
            a = rd.randint(0, 9)

        b = rd.randint(0, 9)
        c = a + b

        if c >= 10:
            c -= 10

        number += str(a) + str(b) + str(c)

    return int(number)

print(numchoose(15))
```

Comment: Whats the if `i == 1 and a == 0` for?

Comment: code seems to be working very well. I just don't exactly understand how it works. can you explain little bit more in depth?

Comment: This prevents the first number from being a 0, but there is probably a better way to do this

Comment: The answer from @Evorage is more compact, however i dont think it would work as well if you want to have 0 being a number. Cant write this on his post, dont have enough reputation :)

Comment: And if there is a part of the code that is unclear, just write witch part and i can try and explain as best as possible.

Comment: I don't understand how if i == 1 and a == 0:numchoose(len) part works. How can you call function to itself

Comment: if the first number is 0, the number will be 14 numbers long

Comment: first number must not be 0 because I want code that creates 15 digit integer

Comment: @eav28 ive updated my answer and it always gives a 15 length string without the `i == 1 and a == 0` thing. It includes 0 as a number

Comment: actually, i was a bit wrong. you can only call on a function when not returning a value. So i changed the answer a bit :)

Comment: @eav28 ah :) okay

Comment: @eav28 _"And if there is a part of the code that is unclear, just write witch part and i can try and explain as best as possible."_ This is why code-only answers are discouraged. While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: You should prefer `len//3` to `int(len/3)`.  And don't call your variables `len` or any other reserved word in Python, you're asking for trouble and confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Bit more compact then @eav28 but credit goes to them for answering first:

```
import random

def NumberGen(Length):
    Number = ""
    for X in range(int(Length // 3)):
        A = random.randint(0, 9)
##      To drop leading zero's:
##      if X == 0 and A == 0:
##          A = random.randint(1, 9)
        B = random.randint(0, 9)
        C = A + B
        if C > 9:
            C -= 10
        Number += str(A) + str(B) + str(C)
    return Number

print(NumberGen(15))
```

I hope this answers your question

Comment: If you wanted to avoid a leading zero you could make a simple modification: `A = random.randint(0 if Number else 1, 9)`

Comment: @MarkRansom whats wrong with a leading 0? Surely they want proper random numbers

Comment: They also want the number to be a particular length, and leading zeros are usually dropped.  The other answer has that assumption, I just wanted to point out how easy it is to modify your answer if that truly becomes a requirement.

Comment: @MarkRansom I've modified my answer, I hope it's to your liking?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer.  I had suggested this method in a comment but never followed through.

```
three_digit_combos = []
for first_digit in range(10):
    for second_digit in range(10):
        third_digit = (first_digit + second_digit) % 10
        combo = first_digit * 100 + second_digit * 10 + third_digit
        three_digit_combos.append(combo)

def numchoose(num_digits):
    assert(num_digits % 3 == 0)
    num = random.choice(three_digit_combos[10:]) # first choice can't start with 0
    for i in range(1, num_digits // 3):
        num = num * 1000 + random.choice(three_digit_combos)
    return num
```